# Attacking two sum problem with a non-brute approach

Tags: python, algorithm, loops

I am learning to code in python, and have written the following code to solve the two sum problem in a list. 
My approach is as follows :

1. Take up an element in the list L
2. subtract the element value from the target sum
3. Check if this value is there anywhere in the list
4. If it is there add its index it to a new list and remove this value 
   from the original list L

My code runs well if I remove the 'remove' command but gives double results. Please help me in identifying the error.

```py
l=[]
def two_sum(l,sval):
    result=[]
    for i in range(len(l)):
        new=sval-l[i]
        if new in l:
            result=result+[(i,l.index(new))]
            l.remove(new) 
    return(result)
```

Comment: First, make your question more clear. Provide the actual problem you're trying to solve. Second, how do you call the function ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `list index out of range` is the Error that you receive. The reason is that you should never remove item when iterate a list in `for loop`: the list has been shortened because the corresponding index in range (0, Len(l)) was removed.

I think a `while loop` with two indicators serve better for this purpose. Try this:

```
def two_sum(l,sval):
    i=0
    j=0
    result=[]
    while i<len(l):
        new=sval-l[i]
        if new in l[j:]:
            result=result+[(i,l.index(new))]
            l[i], l[j]=l[j],l[i]
            j+=1
        i+=1
    return result, l[j:]
```

So if you test:

```
l=list(np.arange(0,10,1))
two_sum(l,10)
```

it returns:

```
([(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 5)], [0, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Where `[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 5)]` are the pairs
and `[0, 6, 7, 8, 9]` is the original list with *summed objects* removed.

Plus I guess it is slightly more efficient than the codes you provided: notice that the line `if new in l[j:]:` omit items that have been looped, so that it returns a *summed pair* only once.